# Select query depends on many possibilities

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have **4 Select in HTML** `users`, `industry`, `lead_source` and `country`. These selects have default value which is equal to **select**.

I want to make a query to select row from table **leads** where the only selected values.

This is the html code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="lead_source">
       <option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
       @foreach($leadssource as $leadsource)
               <option value="{{ $leadsource -> name }}">{{ $leadsource -> name }}</option>
       @endforeach
 </select>

<select class="form-control" name="industry">
    <option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
    @foreach($industries as $industry)
        <option value="{{ $industry -> name }}">{{ $industry -> name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="user">
    <option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user -> name }}">{{ $user -> name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="country">
    <option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
    @foreach($countries as $country)
        <option value="{{ $country -> name }}">{{ $country -> name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I want to select only the values which is not equal to first option which is **select**.

> I have tried:

To use **if statements** and check all the available possibilities but it is not good because if I added one more option then I have to add more bunch of if statements.

Here is a example of my first if statement if all options is selected:

```
if($leadSource != 'select' && $industry != 'select' && $user != 'select' && $country != 'select'){
    $leads = Main::where('lead_source', '=', $leadSource)
                -> where('industry', '=', $industry) -> where('country', '=', $country) -> where('user', '=', $user) -> paginate(50);


    return view('filter.show') -> withLeads($leads);
}
```

Comment: There have show any error message? when you filter.

Comment: You need to filter for each condition individually, not for all together.

Comment: No everything works perfectly and I get the results that I want but the problem here is that I have bunch of if statements for every possibility..

Comment: @jeroen the problem is that user can select one or two or three or the four together

Comment: If you split your condition in 4 conditions, you solve that problem automatically.

Comment: How? Do you mean I have to check for the values `!= 'select'`? If yes then it wont get the results because user may enter two values or three or four @jeroen

Answer (score 1):

You may try as:

```
$query = Main::query();

if(some_filter) {
  $query->where(...)
}
if(some_more_filter) {
  $query->where(...)
}

$leads = $query->paginate(50);
```

**Update**

You can chain the query according to the if conditions as:

```
$query = Main::query();

if($leadSource != 'select') {
    $query->where('lead_source', '=', $leadSource)
}

if($industry != 'select') {
    $query->where('industry', '=', $industry)
}

if($user != 'select') {
    $query->where('user', '=', $user)
}

if($country != 'select') {
    $query->where('country', '=', $country)
}

$leads = $query->paginate(50);
```

Comment: the problem here is that I need to make many conditions for every possibility because the user can select one or two or three or the four together..

Comment: Can you show your full query, so that I can try to reduce that?

Comment: sure..

`$leads = Main::where('lead_source', '=', $leadSource)
                                -> where('industry',    '=', $industry)
                                -> where('user_id',     '=', $userId)
                                -> where('country',     '=', $country)
                                -> paginate(100);`

Comment: Do you have single if statement or multiple? If you have multiple ifs then can you show how you implemented it?

Comment: I have four conditions.. I want to check if one is empty or all or some of them and select from my table depends on the result